# Not save upload image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-6

When I implement the following code, it has to display the selected image in the image tag and upload this image to the api, and in that api there is the receiver for the image and holds the path_image key and loads the image into the server and then saves the data, but in the next process it does not save the image

I tracked the values and found that the image file is not sent to the server

```
<form id="imageUploadForm" class="ms-5 me-5 g-3"
                     method="POST"
                      enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @method('PUT')
                    <input id="path_image" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" class="invisible" type="file"
                           name="path_image" onchange="readURL(this);" style="display: none;"/>
                    <a class="nav-text-user nav-link  fw-bold rounded-circle"
                       style="margin-left: 36%;margin-right: 36%;height: 100px;width: 100px;"
                       href="#">
                        <div class="profile-item">
                            <img id="image_view" class="rounded-circle img-profile mx-auto"
                                 src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name={{$user->name}}" onclick="changePicture();"
                                 alt="">
                            <div class="text-center pt-5 img-profile-change">
                                <i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </form>
```

```
<script>
    try {
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#image_view')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(100)
                        .height(100);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                submit();
                /*document.getElementById('imageUploadForm').submit();*/
            }
        }

        function submit() {
            var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("imageUploadForm"));
            $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update/user/{{$user->id}}",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer {{$user->api_token}}',
                },
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("success");
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }

        function changePicture() {
            document.getElementById('path_image').click();
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
</script>
```

```
 if (User::where('id', $id)->exists()) {
            $user = User::find($id);
            if ($request->hasFile('Path_Image')) {
                $image_profile = Uploading::uploade_image($request->file('Path_Image'), $this->path_profile);
                $user->Path_Image = $image_profile;
            }
            $user->save();
            toastSuccess('تم حفظ الصورة بنجاح');
            return redirect()->route('home');
        } else {
            toastError('فشل حفظ الصورة');
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
```

Comment: You have `reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);`, but don't assign it to anything - what are you trying to do there?

Comment: I have modified the question ...